# Help: Application crashes on accessing source code

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Here is a simple asm code I have inserted in VC++ project. addr_curr_ebp is the current address of EBP pointer. It is pointing to the old EBP value inside the stack frame. 4 bytes after this is the return address inside the application function. I extract a single byte from the code section. I run my code along with other applications like gtalk, vlc etc. The application always crashes when I include ProbStat 1 and 2 in my code. When I remove these statements everything works fine. What do you think this is?

```
__asm{
       push eax
       push ebx
       push cx

       mov ebx, addr_curr_ebp
       mov eax, [ebx + 4]

       mov cl, BYTE PTR [eax - 5]  //ProbStat 1
       mov ret_5, cl  // ProbStat 2

       pop cx
       pop ebx
       pop eax
}
```

Comment: Does it crash or exception, and where exactly does this happen? Have you tried setting the debugger to break on all exception types?

Comment: You're saving nothing by pushing just `CX`.  Also note that MS uses the `ECX` register for the `this` pointer in C++.  Otherwise there's not enough info to answer your question.

Comment: @JimR: 'push cx' saves the cx register, and 'pop cx' restores it. In between, only cl is changed. So ecx is preserved.

Comment: @TonyK: You miss my point.  `push ECX` would be no more expensive and maybe less so, since CX has to be widened to 32 bits before going on the stack.

Comment: @JimR: Sorry, you're right, I misinterpreted 'saving' as 'preserving'.(See my comment to Hans Passant's answer for a possible reason!) But I would be surprised if 'push cx' and 'push ecx' ever had different timings. Somebody here may know better.

Comment: @TonyK: Not a problem.  The reason I mentioned `push CX` vs. `push ECX` was something I saw in a Michael Abrash book or article.  It mentioned the side effects on the pipeline of hidden or not so well known properties of instructions.  This is one of the reasons why I put this in a comment instead of an answer.  Hans beat me to the `this` pointer in `ECX` part of the answer. :)  I think Hans' brain is connected to SO directly...

Comment: I ran a debugger and it breaks at ProbStat1 showing an Access Violation reading location 0xzzzzzz error. Is there a way around this? Will putting it in a try catch block help?

Comment: @Bruce there's not enough code for me to answer your last question.  How addr_curr_ebp is defined is key.  Is it a pointer to a structure.

Comment: @JimR: it is a 32 bit hexadecimal number. The address is vaild as I get some valid values in ret_5 before the program crashes

Comment: @Bruce: Try/catch around that code is not a good idea.  If it doesn't crash all the time, without seeing more code I can only guess what's going on.  If I understand your question, you're using stuff from the calling functions' stack frame.  Do you have frame pointer optimizations turned on?  You might have a calling function with no stack frame which means you're accessing garbage.  Set a breakpoint at the point it would crash and sample a few different calls to the function to see if `addr_curr_ebp` and `*addr_curr_ebp` are valid.

Comment: @Bruce: It's also possible, if you have the option turned on, that whole program optimization is causing this.  Turn it off and test.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet isn't good enough to see where "ret_5" is located.  You'll get an automatic crash if it is a member of a class.  The ecx register stores the "this" pointer, you're messing it up.

Not sure what this does, sound to me like you need to use the _ReturnAddress intrinsic.  It returns the address of the instruction *after* the call instruction that called this code.  Assign it to an unsigned char*, no need for assembly this way.

Comment: The 'this' pointer isn't used in this asm block, and it's restored before exit, so it doesn't matter that ecx is temporarily changed. But, as you say, if ret_5 is a class member then the code won't work as intended.

Comment: @Hans: I used EDX instead of CX (just to be sure) and I made ret_5 a global variable but it still crashes. For Gtalk I get an error saying "Google Talk encountered an internal error, and must now close. Ok to report this error to Google?"

Comment: Click Yes, maybe a miracle happens.  I don't have a clue from the provided info, you need to improve your question.

Comment: This code is part of a Stack Walk code which traverses all the stack frames. I have inserted the assembly inside the StalkWalk function to extract the CALL statement before the return address of each frame. Thats it nothing fancy. Please tell me if you need any more info

Comment: And no miracle happens when I click yes :)

Comment: The StalkWalk function I mentioned earlier uses StackWalk64() to extract the frames. We can get the function's base address (which is why I am extracting the CALL statement) using SymGetSymFromAddr64() once we know the return address. But for gtalk functions we can't get it because the symbol table is not available. I can get the function address using this hack but googletalk.exe crashes when I do this

Comment: You cannot generally safely walk the stack without debug info.  The FPO optimization (frame pointer omission) makes it perilous, no EBP value is available.  /Oy compile option for MSVC.  On of the better named command line options.

Comment: The StackWalk function has not been written by me. I got the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx